# Class Loader error in Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, eclipse-rcp, classloader

I am developing plugins for an Eclipse-RCP-Application. One plugin, uses a jar-file (RGG.jar) via the lib-folder which I am developing by myself as a separate Eclipse project (no plugin). 
Recently, I had a change in my plugin. Instead of using org.apache.commons.lang via the lib-folder, I now can import it as a plugin. But this went along with a version change from 2.something to 3.something. So far, so good.
Since then, I get the following error message during runtime:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/exception/NestableException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.defineClass(ClasspathManager.java:632)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:586)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClassImpl(ClasspathManager.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.classpath.ClasspathManager.findLocalClass(ClasspathManager.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.findLocalClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findLocalClass(BundleLoader.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at de.mpicbg.knime.scripting.core.rgg.RGGDialogPanel.initRGGPanel(RGGDialogPanel.java:41)
    at de.mpicbg.knime.scripting.core.rgg.RGGDialogPanel.<init>(RGGDialogPanel.java:31)
    at de.mpicbg.knime.scripting.core.TemplateConfigurator.reconfigureUI(TemplateConfigurator.java:59)
    at de.mpicbg.knime.scripting.core.ScriptProvider.setContent(ScriptProvider.java:61)
    at de.mpicbg.knime.scripting.core.ScriptingNodeDialog.useTemplate(ScriptingNodeDialog.java:254)
    at de.mpicbg.knime.scripting.core.rgg.wizard.UseTemplateListenerImpl.useTemplate(UseTemplateListenerImpl.java:28)
    at de.mpicbg.knime.scripting.core.rgg.wizard.ScriptTemplateWizard.useTemplateActionPerformed(ScriptTemplateWizard.java:255)
    at de.mpicbg.knime.scripting.core.rgg.wizard.ScriptTemplateWizard.categoryTreeMouseClicked(ScriptTemplateWizard.java:263)
    at de.mpicbg.knime.scripting.core.rgg.wizard.ScriptTemplateWizard.access$2(ScriptTemplateWizard.java:261)
    at de.mpicbg.knime.scripting.core.rgg.wizard.ScriptTemplateWizard$2.mouseClicked(ScriptTemplateWizard.java:357)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6538)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4534)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.lang.exception.NestableException cannot be found by de.mpicbg.knime.scripting.core_3.1.0.qualifier
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 55 more
```

This error comes up in my plugin, the first time I try to use functionality from the RGG.jar. The RGG-jar contains the commons-lang-2.2-jar in its lib-folder. So I assume that this causes the problem?

If that is the case, what would I have to do? Updating the commons-lang-...-jar to 3.something?
If this is not the reason, can you help me to find out what causes the problem. (things have worked at some point before...)

Comment: You say Eclipse RCP but the stack trace seems to be mostly an AWT/Swing application; not an RCP. Most Eclipse/OSGi plugins won't run in a plain Java app.

Comment: @greg-449 - hmm, I know, that my plugins are for an RCP-application (and working without problems since some years). Probably, there are design mistakes (I'm not very experienced with the different concepts), but as I said - it worked before...

Comment: Can you clarify how you are using the RGG.jar? Is it a separate bundle? Or have you put it on the `Bundle-ClassPath`? Where are the commons-lang classes?

Comment: I tried to explain, let me know what is not understandable. The RGG is a separate ant-project (simple eclipse java project, no plugin), where I build the jar from. This jar is then copied into the lib-folder of the plugin to be available. The commons-lang classes are imported via 'required plugins' on the plugin side. In the RGG-project I have a commons-lang-jar in the lib-folder of the project.